# How to change menu item behavior as "on hover change background", with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, xhtml, twitter-bootstrap

As you see on default twitter bootstrap navbar menu only the active menu item's background is different then other. 
What I want is when I'm on a menu item, I want the background to be changed to another color. 
The bottom line, I should act as active one when I'm on hover of the menu item.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone here is wrong, after some testing you'll find this CSS to change menu hover.

```
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {background-color:red;}
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an inline style or different id to the li on that particular **page** and style it to your liking. If you dont have access to that you have to do it using Jquery. Does that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your css:

```
.navbar .nav > a:hover {background-color:#f60;}
```

I hope this helps, I'm a little confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: I tried this. However it didn't work. Basically when someone is over an menu item the background with change a:hover should have worked but there should be something that we are missing. For instance, there is "Questions" menu item at the top of the stackoverflow. First one is active. When you come over to any link background changes. That's the same thing that I want.

Comment: Try putting it at the bottom of the CSS file.

Comment: I have already done. I have other css edits too. They worked great. However, only this one has problem.

Comment: .navbar .nav li > a:hover {background-color:#f60;} solved problem

Comment: Just tested it, this works: .navbar .nav > li:hover a {background-color:#f60;}

Comment: The only problem is  "active" one there is a small padding occurs when I'm on hover it. I'm trying to figure out how can I closed that padding(gap). If you can help me about it it would be great. and I think this will be the answer :) I think all of li items has either margin or padding.

Comment: Okay found .nav a{ margin:0;}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10725/discussion-between-snare-and-drawrdesign)

Answer (score 0):

Check answer by @martincho- it worked for me in changing the blue hover color:

Don't change `bootstrap.css`. Create another `css` file where you can override this. Anyway, the line is 4572:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a
```

Set `background-image` to none, and `background-color` to whatever color you want.